# Перемещение QWidget C++

Tags: c++, qt

Создал `QWidget` с именем `WPunktDialog` в `QMainWidget`. Интересует вопрос, как заставить `QWidget` двигатся при нажатии на него и перемещения мышки, т.е как обычное окно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через метод [QWidget::move](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#pos-prop)

У метода такая сигнатура:

```
void move(int x, int y)
void move(const QPoint &)
```

Пример:

```
QWidget w;
w.show();
w.move(100, 100);
```

---

Чтобы для двигать виджеты мышкой нужно переопределить события `mousePressEvent` и `mouseMoveEvent`:

```
class Widget: public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit Widget(QWidget *parent=0) : QWidget(parent) {

        }

    protected:
        void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
        {
            if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
                oldPos = event->pos();
            }
        }

        void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
        {
            QPoint delta = event->pos() - oldPos;
            move(pos() + delta);
        }

    private:
        QPoint oldPos;
};
```

Честно говоря, у меня рядом `Qt`/`Qt Creator` не было, поэтому изначально код [на питоне писал](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/beae3f887eb9bd63a8cb2a2cbee9cb7da1558082/pyqt__mouse_manual_move.py), а после переписывал на `с++`, поэтому проверить его возможности не было, но должно работать.

Comment: Разве в этом случает он не будет рисоваться на том месте куда указан а при нажатии на него мышкой и пробовать переместить он реагировать не будет?

Comment: Виджеты без родителей становятся полноценными окнами, и их можно перемещать мышкой и менять их размер как у настоящих окон. Виджет с стандартными флагами берег рамку окна у оконного менеджера операционной системы

Comment: Хм. виджет создан через `Ui-Editor` в `Qt`, разве он имеет автоматически родителя? Также вызывается через нажатию на кнопку `ui->WPunktDialog.show();`

Comment: Если виджет не находится внутри другого виджета, то у него нет родителя, попробуйте: `ui->WPunktDialog.move(300, 300);`

Comment: слегка не то) но все равно спасибо

Comment: а, понял, покажу пример, но позже. А так, я такое тут использовал: https://github.com/gil9red/NotesManager/blob/master/Note/abstractnotehead.cpp#L67

Comment: одно не пойму, где происходит отловка, на виджет по имени? просто не все виджеты могут быть передвинутыми

Comment: Мой ответ не подходит?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71769/discussion-between-insider-and-gil9red).